# best way to export MySQL database to SqlServer database

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a MySQL database, i need that database in MS SqlServer. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

there are few methods out there 
like

install mysql driver --> connect to mysql using ODBC --> create a link server --> use openquery

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29106/Migrate-MySQL-to-Microsoft-SQL-Server

another method 
export from mysql to excel worksheet and then import the excel worksheet.

the method i usually use, and which i think is the reliable for me, is a manual and lengthy process

i use phpmyadmin to export the DB in a sql script

and than i manually tweak the script

like for example change the `table name` to [tablename] and other sql syntax
etc